# How to check Apple Application Support is installed on Windows?

Tags: itunes

I have a program depends on an open source library called libimobiledevice, this library depends on Apple Application Support, and if that was not installed, my program will be crashed without friendly prompt message. So I'd like to add a front-end program, when it starts, check Apple Application Support is installed, and if that was not installed, I will provide a message like "iTunes installation's required" to tell user.

P.S. I am using GCC C/C++.

Comment: Please include a tag to indicate the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a way by query registry on Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>

bool AppleApplicationSupportIsInstalled(){
  return RegQueryValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Apple Inc.\\Apple Application Support", NULL, NULL);
}
```